# Convert a python csv list to spark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, databricks-sql

I have a python csv list:

```
result =['2016,F,555123,031a1f7d-1885-4719-95e6-d4b851633fe1', '2016,F,555123,23300425-c475-465a-8bf1-e306fa5bd9d1]
```

I'd like to convert this csv list to a Spark Dataframe and should be able to query individual columns.
I tried below, but no luck

```
testSchema = StructType([       
    StructField('col1', StringType(), True),
    StructField('col2', StringType(), True),
    StructField('col3', StringType(), True),
    StructField('id', StringType(), True)
])

rdd = sc.parallelize([result])
frame = spark.read.schema(testSchema).csv(rdd)
display(frame)
```

The above code is displaying only the first row and that too with , and [

| col1 | col2 | col3 | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ['2016 | F | 555123 | 031a1f7d-1885-4719-95e6-d4b851633fe1' |

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated !!

Comment: What happens if you change `[result]` to `result`?

Comment: did you try `rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([x.split(',') for x in result])` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your csv list has a quote missing at the end, right before square bracket. Other than that, as @mkrieger1 suggested, you need to drop the square brackets when you parallelize as 'result' is already a list. Did not find any other problem with your code.

```
result = ['2016,F,555123,031a1f7d-1885-4719-95e6-d4b851633fe1', '2016,F,555123,23300425-c475-465a-8bf1-e306fa5bd9d1']

testSchema = StructType([       
    StructField('col1', StringType(), True),
    StructField('col2', StringType(), True),
    StructField('col3', StringType(), True),
    StructField('id', StringType(), True)])

rdd = sc.parallelize(result)

frame = spark.read.schema(testSchema).csv(rdd)

frame.show(2, False)

+----+----+------+------------------------------------+
|col1|col2|col3  |id                                  |
+----+----+------+------------------------------------+
|2016|F   |555123|031a1f7d-1885-4719-95e6-d4b851633fe1|
|2016|F   |555123|23300425-c475-465a-8bf1-e306fa5bd9d1|
+----+----+------+------------------------------------+
```